# how to replace java.sql.sqldata as it's unsupported in tibero

Tags: tibero

as java.sql.sqldata is not supported in tibero jdbc driver, we'd like to know how to modify it or any replacement

is java.sql.Array a replacement of java.sql.sqldata?

there's no code so far

if we implement java.sql.sqldata in tibero, we will hit the following error: Cause: java.sql.SQLException: JDBC-90608:Invalid input parameter

Comment: unsupported doc: https://technet.tmaxsoft.com/upload/download/online/tibero/pver-20140922-000001/tibero_dev/ch02.html

Comment: any workaround or replacement for java.sql.sqldata would be appreciated